# Java -- referencing a method in different class

Tags: java, inheritance, extend

I am coming from C programming, so I m new to the OOP concept. My question is this:

I am trying to test a bunch of modules, so I decided to write a wrapper class for the common functionality, so I can call these methods from other classes. But where I am confused is if I make the other classes `extends` from `myWrapperClass`, I cannot still use the methods of the wrapper classes unless they are defined `static` (and most tutorials says try to stay away from static if possible) or I need to create a new instance of the wrapper class using `new`.

Then what is the point of using `extends`? If that is the way I have to go, is there any short cut using them instead of writing `myclass.wrapperclassfunction()` each time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see some example code?

Comment: Those functions that define in the parent class (wrapperclass) can be extended to their children class. In your children class, you can just call the method from wrapperclass, or you can just override it

Comment: I get the sense that there are multiple issues that needs to be addressed in your OOP knowledge gap.  "I need to create a new instance of the wrapper class using "new". then what is the point of using extend."  Punctuation aside, that really makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

> so I can call these methods from other classes. but where I am confused is. if I make the other classes extends from myWrapperClass, I cannot still use the methods of the wrapper classes unless they are defined static

This is false.

You can absolutely do this.

```
public class MyWrapperClass {

     public void commonMethod() {
     }

}

public class YourClass extends MyWrapperClass {

     public void anotherMethod() {
            commonMethod();
            // other stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that is his issue. He doesn't understand why objects need to be allocated.

Comment: @alphazero -- the question made it sound to me like the OP thinks that to call a method of a superclass from a subclass, he'd have to either make it static or instantiate the superclass. I was trying to explain that he doesn't have to do either.

Comment: I hear you; It is somewhat difficult to decipher the text so we have to guess until OP decides to 'clarify' his question. Anyway he said "I cannot still use" so I assumed he actually tried it. And if he indeed has a simple extension and has instantiated the child, how could he possibly "cannot still use" the base class methods?  I'm betting on his C pedigree :)

Answer (score 0):

If the common functionality is identical methods in various modules (subclasses), then you can just factor it out of the modules into the common superclass and just have the method defined once there. If the method is implemented in a different way in every subclass but you want to call it in the same way regardless of which subclass instance you have, then you can declare it as `abstract` in the superclass and have an implementation in each subclass. If it's something in between — all but a few subclasses have the same implementation — then you can factor out the most common implementation into the superclass and override it in the exceptional subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

[edit summary of issue of OP]:

You need to review the distinction between primitive and object types in Java.

A primitive type can simply be declared and used:

```
   int f; // Java (or is c? :)
   f = 10;
```

An object type must be allocated. (For C programmers: Java objects are dynamically allocated.  Think heap, not stack.)

```
   Foo myFoo = new Foo(); // Java
   struct foo *myFoo = (struct foo *) malloc(sizeof(struct foo)); // good old C
```

-- initial answer --

Your point of confusion is this:

Reading between the lines, it seems that you think that by *merely* informing the type system that an extension of the base exists, you should be able to magically start calling methods on that *type*.

And this is why you have settled on static methods: they don't require creating an instance -- something which apparently you refuse to do!

Let's say you have something along the lines of Kai's answer (which is correct btw) above.

Then:

```
/** using Kai's classes */
public void foobar() {
   YourClass foo = new YourClass();
   foo.commonMethod();  // try it ..   
}
```

Review what you *must* know of *simply* defining and using a `struct` in `C`.

Now **forget** this:

```
  typedef struct {
          int foo;
          char bar[3];
  } extended;

  extended s;  // this is not just declaring s; it is also allocating it
  s.foo = 10;  // hey, no malloc. nasty Java insists on new ..
```

In Java, when you say:

```
   SomeClass s; // s declared but not instantiated (think 'allocated')
```

you must then instantiate the object.

```
  s = new SomeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you declare your wrapperclassfunction is **not private** in your wrapperclass.

```
public class wrapperClasss{

private wrapperMethod(){}
}

public class Myclass extends wrapperClasss{

  private myMethod(){
    wrapperMethod();//this is a compile erro
   }
}
```